# Why doesn't PyCharm run a flask webapp in HTTPS?

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I have included the following line of code at the end of my application:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc")
```

But the output that I get when I run the project in PyCharm is

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, when I run the application from the terminal (Alt+F12) using the command python app.py
I get the output

```
* Running on https://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

What is the reason behind this? Is there no way to run it using PyCharm? Typing the command each time is quite tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first:

```
# get app from somewhere
app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc")
```

It will only work when you directly launch the script like `python main.py`. As in this case, the `__name__` equals to `"__main__"`.

Second, when you use `flask run` to run your application which I suppose is the way your IDE uses, the `if` condition will be `False`, so this line `app.run(ssl_context="adhoc")` will not even run.

---

Finally, if you want to use it in production, you should configure `app` directly. Or use a reversed proxy server such as `nginx`. Actually I recommend the latter approach.

Answer (score 2):

Add the option `--cert=adhoc` to your server configuration in your `Run/Debug Configurations` menu in Pycharm.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it but the changes are pretty high that you may start your application with `flask run`. You may try to set it as standard python project with basic start up command such as: `python application.py`

Comment: but if i deploy my project on a webserver, will it have any effect of the fact that the flask command doesn't work?

Comment: you should not use flask build-in werkzeug server at 'web server'. use [uwsgi](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/uwsgi/) or [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) instead.